# a tag disappear in safari because of encodeURI()

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, materialize

I created a card, which shows random Quotes.
Below the card should be a custom tweet link. I used materializeCSS for creating this card. (https://materializecss.com/cards.html => basic card) 
Problem:

It works in chrome but in safari the whole  tag is disappearing. After debugging I found out that the href with encodeURI() is the problem, but according to google Safari supports encodeURI().

React.js Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import '../../styles/quote.css'
const Quote = ({ assignNewQuoteIndex, selectedQuote }) => {
    return (
        <div id="startSpace">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s10 offset-s1 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-content">
                        <div className="row">
                                <div className="right">
                                    <a href='!#' onClick={assignNewQuoteIndex}>
                                        <i className="material-icons hoverable" id="refresh" >autorenew</i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <span className="card-title">"{selectedQuote.quote}"</span>
                        <p>-{selectedQuote.author}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-action">
                            <a className="center btn-small" target="_blank" rel='noopener noreferrer'
                            href={encodeURI(`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="${selectedQuote.quote}" - ${selectedQuote.author}&hashtags=MohrQuotes`)}
                            ><i className="fa fa-twitter" id="tweet"></i>  Tweet</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Quote
```

CSS

```
.card{
    background-color:#2B2928;
    font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
    color: #fff;
}
#btnSmall{
    background-color:#fff;
    color: #2B2928;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#startSpace{
    padding-top: 3vw;
    padding-bottom: 1vw;
}
#refresh{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

When i delete this line or use a normal href (e.g. href="#"), the button will be shown in safari:

```
    href={encodeURI(`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="${selectedQuote.quote}" - ${selectedQuote.author}&hashtags=MohrQuotes`)}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens if you use encodeURIComponent instead?   (EncodeURI does not escape the symbols in your query string).   Also, you can try putting the query string in a var first to avoid the ${selectedQuote.stuff} being passed to encodeURI/encodeURIComponent if possible.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. When I use encodeURIComponent the a tag will be shown, but the link do not work. It opens my site again. I tried to store the URL in a var but it do not make a difference. How can i use the EncodeURI right, so that it escape the symbols?

Comment: EncodeURI won't work for that URL... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI